# How do I use a combo-box to change the sort order?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor

In My view I have a collection of the user uploads and I have added a combo box with action links to refresh the view to select the new sort order:

```
@model IEnumerable<FunPetPics.Models.PetPhotoModel>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<p>
    <a asp-action="UploadPhoto">Upload Photo</a>
</p>
@if (Model == null || !Model.Any())
{
    <p>Your uploads will be displayed here</p>

}
else
{

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h6>Order by:</h6>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type=text list=sortOrder class="list">
                <datalist id=sortOrder>
                    <option>@Html.ActionLink("Newest", "Index", new { sortOrder = "Newest" })</option>
                    <option>@Html.ActionLink("Oldest", "Index", new { sortOrder = "Oldest" })</option>
                    <option>@Html.ActionLink("Cutest", "Index", new { sortOrder = "Cutest" })</option>
                    <option>@Html.ActionLink("Funiest", "Index", new { sortOrder = "Funiest" })</option>
                    <option>@Html.ActionLink("Most Awsome", "Index", new { sortOrder = "Most Awsome" })</option>
                </datalist>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />

    <div class="card-columns">

        @foreach (var upload in Model)
        {
            <div class="card">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="@("~/UploadedPhotos/"+  upload.ImageName)" asp-append-version="true">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">@upload.Title</h4>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">@upload.PetName</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">@upload.DateUploaded</p>
                    <p class="card-text">@upload.Description</p>
                    <p class="card-subtitle">Ratings:</p>
                    <p class="card-text">
                        Cute:@upload.AverageCutenessRating/5<br />
                        Funny:@upload.AverageFunnynessRating/5<br />
                        Awsome:@upload.AverageAwsomnessRating/5<br />
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

}
```

In my controller I get the user's list of uploads with a switch statement which changes the order based on the `sortOrder` parameter, then return the view with the model:

```
 public IActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
        {
            //get the current logged in user and their collection of uploads from the database context
            var uploads = GetLoggedInUser().Uploads;
           
            if (uploads == null || !uploads.Any())
            {
                return View();
            }

            switch (sortOrder)
            {
                case "Newest":
                    uploads.OrderByDescending(u => u.DateUploaded);
                    break;

                case "Oldest":
                    uploads.OrderBy(u => u.DateUploaded);
                    break;

                case "Cutest":
                    uploads.OrderByDescending(u => u.AverageCutenessRating)
                        .ThenByDescending(u => u.DateUploaded);
                    break;

                case "Funniest":
                    uploads.OrderByDescending(u => u.AverageFunnynessRating)
                        .ThenByDescending(u => u.DateUploaded);
                    break;

                case "Most Awsome":
                    uploads.OrderByDescending(u => u.AverageAwsomnessRating)
                        .ThenByDescending(u => u.DateUploaded);
                    break;

                default:
                    sortOrder = "Newest";
                    uploads.OrderByDescending(u => u.DateUploaded);
                    break;
            }

            return View(uploads.ToList());
        }
```

First problem: Selecting an item from the menu does not click in the hyperlink, it just removes other items from the list [image]

Second Problem: When trying to navigate manually using `localhost:44316/UserUploads?sortOrder="Oldest"` in the URL and refresh the page the `sortOrder` in the controller is null so the order does not change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Selecting an item from the menu does not click in the hyperlink

`datalist` doesn't support forms or links. they just supply a dropdown list for an input. So the ActionLink can not work here, you should use js or jquery to refresh the page.

> it just removes other items from the list

Actually, they are not removed. datalist has a built-in `autocomplete` attribute , so after you select an option to the input, the others are invisiable. You need to clear the input first.

> When trying to navigate manually using localhost:44316/UserUploads?sortOrder="Oldest" in the URL and refresh the page the sortOrder in the controller is null so the order does not change

No need to add double quotes in querystring.

```
localhost:44316/UserUploads?sortOrder=Oldest
```

I made a demo according to your needs, you can refer to it.

**Index.cshtml:**

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="UploadPhoto">Upload Photo</a>
</p>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h6>Order by:</h6>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" id="sortOrder" name="sortOrder" list="orderList" value="@ViewBag.sortOrder">
            <datalist id="orderList">
                <option>@Html.ActionLink("Newest", "Index", new { sortOrder = "Newest" })</option>
                <option>@Html.ActionLink("Oldest", "Index", new { sortOrder = "Oldest" })</option>
                <option>@Html.ActionLink("Cutest", "Index", new { sortOrder = "Cutest" })</option>
                <option>@Html.ActionLink("Funiest", "Index", new { sortOrder = "Funiest" })</option>
                <option>@Html.ActionLink("Most Awsome", "Index", new { sortOrder = "Most Awsome" })</option>
            </datalist>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br />

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $("#sortOrder").bind('input', function () {
            if (checkExists($('#sortOrder').val()) === true) {
                var url = '@Url.Action("Index", "UserUploads")';
                var text = $('#sortOrder').val();
                switch (text) {
                    case "Newest":
                        url = url +"?sortOrder=Newest";
                        break;
                    case "Oldest":
                        url = url +"?sortOrder=Oldest";
                        break;
                    case "Cutest":
                        url = url +"?sortOrder=Cutest";
                        break;
                    case "Funiest":
                        url = url +"?sortOrder=Funiest";
                        break;
                    case "Most Awsome":
                        url = url +"?sortOrder=Most Awsome";
                        break;
                    default:
                        url = '@Url.Action("Index")';
                }
                window.location = url;
            }
        });

        function checkExists(inputValue) {
            console.log(inputValue);
            var x = document.getElementById("orderList");
            var i;
            var flag;
            for (i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
                if (inputValue == x.options[i].value) {
                    flag = true;
                }
            }
            return flag;
        }
    </script>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public class UserUploadsController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(string sortOrder)
    {
        ViewBag.sortOrder = sortOrder;
        return View();
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]